# create batch file for search and remove multiple files

Tags: batch-file

I would like to ask you for help with batch file creation, where I have a list of multiple files in .txt document. These file names need to be searched in Directory with multiple subfolders and once file will be found it need to be deleted.

text file contain approx 18k lines

[image: this is .txt document]

Directory

each have inside more subfolders and then file

[image: sample of structure]

Thank you so much

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Regard that this is not a site to request code for free! Read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Answer (score 0):

Your text file must be in list form:

```
file1.txt
file2.csv
somefile.doc
Some File.xls
...
```

Then your script:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in (filelist.txt) do if exist "%%i" echo del /S "%%i"
```

Once you confirm it does what it should, remove the `echo` to actually delete the files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure findstr will deal well with that file size, but you can try:

```
@echo off
Pushd "X:\path\Storage\0e
Dir /B /S /A-D | findstr /IB /G:"X:\path\tieto.txt" >"X:\path\delete.lst"
```

After reviewing the file `"X:\path\delete.lst"` you can process it with

```
@Echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ("X:\path\delete.lst") do Del "%%A"
```